# Extracted data not processed correctly

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using Python 3 with Beautiful Soup 4 to extract some data from a website then display it on a GUI. Every time it runs, ExtractedValues is left equal to None. How do I fix this mess?

```python
  labels = self.page.findAll("class_='label swap'")
  labelvalue = self.page.findAll("class_='val swap'")

  self.ExtractedValues={}  # Dictionary For Storing Data

  # Checking Data Is Ready For Extracting Automatically
  if len(labels)==len(labelvalue):
   for i in range(len(labels)):
    self.ExtractedValues[labels[i].text.replace('\n','')]=labelvalue[i].get_text().replace('\n','')
    self.ExtractedValues['temperature'] = self.page.find('span',{'class':'temp swap'}).get_text().replace('\n','')
    print (self.ExtractedValues['temperature'])
    self.ExtractedValues['summary'] = self.page.find('span',{'class':'summary swap'}).get_text().replace('\n','')
    print (self.ExtractedValues['summary'])
    self.ExtractedValues['next summary'] = self.page.find('span',{'class':'next swap'}).get_text().replace('\n','')
    print (self.ExtractedValues['next summary'])
    return self.ExtractedValues
  return
```

Comment: can you please share html.

Comment: when using "class_" it is not supposed to be quoted and also the function should be named find_all today (new name). So those lines should read `labels = self.page.find_all(class_="label swap")`etc.